# Insufficient data on cloudwatch alarm created with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-auto-scaling

I have a cw alarm for monitoring the Autoscaling Instance Max Size, enabled GroupTotalInstances metric in Autoscaling group monitoring.

I have created this alarm using terraform, and manually with the same parameters, the one created with terraform give me Insufficient data, while the other one works great.

Compared them with the terraform output everything looks the same, I have other alarms created using terraform which are working great.
Can't get the point what I'm doing wrong here.

```
  resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "asg_max_size" {
  alarm_name                = "test"
  alarm_description         = "test"
  alarm_actions             = ["${var.sns_cw_alarms_topic_arn}"]
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = 1
  datapoints_to_alarm       = 1
  metric_name               = "GroupTotalInstances"
  namespace                 = "AWS/Autoscaling"
  period                    = "${var.alarm_period}"
  statistic                 = "Maximum"
  threshold                 = "${var.instance_max_size}"
  treat_missing_data        = "missing"
  insufficient_data_actions = []
  ok_actions                = []

  dimensions = {
    "AutoScalingGroupName" = "${var.asg_name}"
  }

}
```

Comment: This `"${var.asg_name}"` might be read by terraform as a string literal. Try using `var.asg_name`. Basically you can remove that type of notation anywhere except when there is some kind of string concatenation or similar.

Comment: removed the alarm from the state, deleted from the console and tried the approach without the curly brackets in the dimensions property, but still the alarm showing Insufficient data.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. The namespace value was incorrect.

```BAD:  namespace = "AWS/Autoscaling"
PROPER: namespace = "AWS/AutoScaling"```