# cloudwatch metric alarm stuck on insufficient data

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-aurora, cloudwatch-alarms

I set up cloudwatch metric alarm through terraform and the metric is stuck on insufficient data status. If I repeat the same steps and create it in the UI, the status shows OK. I'm monitoring Amazon Aurora v2. What am I doing wrong?

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "storage_alarm" {
  alarm_name = "rds-storage-alarm"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods = "1"
  metric_name = "TotalBackupStorageBilled"
  namespace = "AWS/RDS"
  period = "300"
  statistic = "sum"
  threshold = "30"
  dimensions = {
    DBInstanceIdentifier="myDB"
  }
}
```

Similar issues to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73701934/insufficient-data-on-cloudwatch-alarm-created-with-terraform) but different resources and no answers given.

Comment: Is the Aurora DB standalone instance or part of a cluster?

Comment: Yes, it's the writer instance of the cluster.

Comment: You might want to try `DBClusterIdentifier` in the dimensions